# Stop overriding object once it has been set dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm creating an object dynamically using dot notation. This part works fine! The issue I have is that I'm overwriting object on each iteration. Once it's set it should just add to the object to overwrite and replace the properties.

What am I doing wrong ?

E.g. `price": { "minPrice": 1000, "maxPrice": 10000 }` not `{ "minPrice": value}` or `{ "maxPrice": value }`.

```
ausedSet(params, key, value);

function ausedSet(object, key, value) {
    var keys = key.split('.');

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
        object = object[keys[i]] = {};

    }
    object[keys[keys.length - 1]] = value;

    return object;
}

function getValidParams(value, key) {
                if (acceptedParameters.indexOf(key) > -1) {
                    populateObject(vm.filterParameters, key, value);
                }
            }
//vm.filterParameters returns these

    var acceptedParameters = [
                    'postCode',
                    'distance',
                    'locale',
                    'vehicleCategory',
                    'resultOrder',
                    'longLatCoordinates',
                    'price.minPrice',
                    'price.maxPrice',
                    'pagination'
                ]
```

Comment: What is this intended to do? `object = object[keys[i]] = {};`   It winds up just creating an empty object, which doesn't seem to be what you want.

Comment: @DanielBeck see my answer... OP is trying to iterate their way through a sequence of nested keys. The function actually works but ends up returning a reference to the innermost object rather than the original input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you're not saving a reference to the original object... you're overwriting your `object` variable in the for-loop and then returning the final value of that variable. Perhaps you should add a line like:

```
var current = object;
```

and then use `current` instead of `object` in the rest of your function. Then you can return `object` and it will be still be a reference to your original input.

**Edit:** OP wasn't using the return value to begin with, so my original solution didn't help. The problem was that OP was passing in related sets of keys ("price.minPrice", "price.maxPrice") and the function was overwriting the value of the initial shared key ("price"). The solution is to check if an object already exists at the key in question before assigning an empty one.

```js
function populateObject(obj, keyString, value) {
    var keys = keyString.split('.'),
        curr = obj;

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
        if (!curr[keys[i]]) curr[keys[i]] = {};
        curr = curr[keys[i]];

    }
    curr[keys[keys.length - 1]] = value;

    return obj;
}

var myObject = { foo: 'bar' };
var result = populateObject(myObject, 'some.nested.keys', 'something');

result = populateObject(result, 'some.nested.other', 'test');

console.log(result === myObject);
console.log(result.foo === 'bar');
console.log(result.some.nested.keys === 'something');
console.log(result.some.nested.other === 'test');
```

Comment: Downvoted? What's going on in this thread?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's a bit hard to see why this would solve the problem. Could you show full code?

Comment: Sure, hold on...

Comment: I still have the same issue - sadly

Comment: Take another look at my code example... I added a test to verify that it works as expected. Could you perhaps edit your original post with the current version of your function?

Comment: I've updated it

Comment: I'm confused... are you passing in an array as the first parameter? I was assuming you were passing in a POJO (plain old Javascript object). Could you show what arguments you're passing into the function and what the expected result is?

Comment: Oh, I see, you're trying to populate vm.filterParameters, which is an object...

Comment: Could you add the line `console.log(vm.filterParameters, key, value)` right before you call populateObject, and then add `console.log(vm.filterParameters)` after the call? And then post what those values are? It might help diagnose the issue.

Comment: Yes thats what I'm trying to do. Sorry for the poor explanation

Comment: {"locale":"en_GB","resultOrder":{"orderBy":"Price","sortOrder":"Ascending"},"vehicleCategory":"Commercial","pagination":{"maxRecords":48,"startingRecord":0},"distance":"10","longLatCoordinates":"-0.12775829999998223,51.5073509","price":{"minPrice":"6000"}}

Comment: Hmm... is that just the output? What are the arguments being passed to the function, and what is the result missing?

Comment: Wait, I think I know what the problem is... if you're repeating this with identical nested keys, you're going to end up overwriting things. I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: Okay, I understand the issue now. You weren't using the return value to begin with, so my original solution was irrelevant. Your problem was that you were filling in the keys with empty objects regardless of whether or not there was already an object there! I've updated my solution to avoid this bug. Hope this helps!

Comment: can I change this to ?  if ((!curr[keys[i]]) curr[keys[i]] = {}){curr = curr[keys[i]]};  Sorry to ask could you update the code with the brackets on the if statement pls. still bit of a noob

Comment: Thanks it seemed to work. Thanks a lot